# breeze.js mixing AND and OR predicates

Tags: breeze, mixing, predicates

I'm trying to configure the proper syntax for breeze.js when mixing AND and OR predicates.  I did not see an example on the breeze site and could not find one anywhere else.

Basically I want to do something like this in my WHERE clause:

```
(
age > 30  AND
sex == 'M' AND
jobStartDate >= '1/1/2000'
)

OR

(
exemptStatus == 1
)
```

this will bring back entities that match the 3 criteria OR are exempt.  I'm using EF6 with ODATA syntax.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  You could easily make two compound predicates and combine them.  This section of the docs describe it - http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/Predicate.html#method_create

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var Predicate = breeze.Predicate;
    var baseQuery = EntityQuery.from("Something");
    var pred1 = new Predicate("age", ">", 30);
    var pred2 = new Predicate("sex", "==", 'M');
    var pred3 = new Predicate("jobStartDate", ">=", new Date(2000,1,1));
    var pred4 = new Predicate("exemptStatus", "==", 1);
    var compositePred = pred1.and(pred2).and(pred3).or(pred4);
    var query = baseQuery.where(compositePredicate);
    myEntityManager.executeQuery(query);
```

or

```
    var compositePred = Predicate.and(pred1, pred2, pred3).or(pred4);
```

Comment: I dont know why my initial version wasn't grouping the ANDs together properly, but your example worked great.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello idea blade. Are you guys thinking up a better way to add predicates? This is verbose and painful. You can do this in c# linq in one statement.